# Django, what is the maximum number of queries per view, which does not cause serious speed issues

Tags: django, performance

I'm new to django, I have this application where each of my views have an average of 6 queries. Is that ok, or  should I optimise my database for better.

Comment: its completely fine but optimizations are always better

Comment: thanq @ArpitSolanki

Comment: The number of queries is only one of many factors that affect performance. Also, we can't judge what performance is acceptable to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram is mainly using Django as their backend framework mainly, and they have a huge amount of user as we know. Their solution for solving your problem is to create multiple data centers to process the request to make it like a distributed system.

In your case, if it is running as a private project and the query is not querying a huge database, I think it is okay.

Comment: thanks @Bob , doing the math, I'll have 300 new users every month, so for a year I'll have 3600 rows. i would like to know about the how huge my database is? Could you please suggest

Comment: databases have very high performance so even if thousands of rows of are there don't worry. although millions of rows need optimizations